# Proxy Chromium for Testing

Tags: proxy, chromium

I'm trying to test nginx as a forward proxy using Chromium (Firefox and others will not use the proxy).

When I open Chromium's Advanced Settings and select "`Change proxy settings...`:

[image: Chromium Advanced Settings]

I'm taken to the Network applet (in Gnome Control Center):

[image: Network in Gnome Control Center]

That changes the proxy settings for the entire machine.

How do I change the proxy settings for just Chromium?

Comment: Not sure if it can be done "in browser", hence answered as a comment, but you can start chromium with switches (for example --proxy-server=host:port) - chromium-browser --help will show you the settings.  I know that for a SOX proxy you need to start it this way as there is no equivalent setting in the program.

Comment: Thanks davidgo. I see `--proxy-server` at [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). However, syntax is not listed. How does one break out HTTP and HTTPS traffic? For example, how do you specify HTTP to port 8080 and HTTPS to 8443?

Comment: according to the help page example:  --proxy-server="https=proxyip:8443;http=proxyip:8080"

Comment: Thanks davidgo, that worked perfectly. By the way, the example page I found at [Run Chromium with flags](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) (referenced by [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)) did not show how to use `--proxy-server`. What page were you on?

Comment: I just typed chromium-browser --help | less.  Glad you got it working

Comment: What if you try with Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> You can start chromium with switches (for example --proxy-server=host:port) - chromium-browser --help will show you the settings. I know that for a SOX proxy you need to start it this way as there is no equivalent setting in the program.
>
> according to the help page example:

```
--proxy-server="https=proxyip:8443;http=proxyip:8080"
```